# PHP Comment Box

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, comments

I have a website which is still under construction.

I have a comment box in PHP which is linked to a mysql database on my godaddy account.

While debugging I discovered that after you leave a comment and you refresh the comment shows up again for some reason.

The link for this website is: www.borgcarr.com

There are two php codes; one in the beginning and one where I require it to display the comments.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<?php
  mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
  mysql_select_db("Comment_Box");
  $name=$_POST['name'];
  $comment=$_POST['comment'];
  $submit=$_POST['submit'];

  $dbLink = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
      mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8", $dbLink);
      mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8", $dbLink);

  if($submit)
  {
  if($name&&$comment)
  {
  $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO Comment_Table (name,comment) VALUES ('$name','$comment') ");
  }
  else
  {
  echo "<script>alert('Please fill out all fields.');</script>";/*echo "please fill out all fields";*/
  }
  }
  ?>


<html>
<head><title>Law Website</title>

  <link href='css/style.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' /> 
    <link href="scripts/6/js-image-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="scripts/6/js-image-slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <center>
  <div id="sitewrapper">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="header_content_left">
        Maltese Law
  </div>
</div>
<div id="menu">
  <div id="menu_left">
    <div id="sliderFrame">
      <div id="slider">
          <img src="images/court1.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="images/court2.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="images/court3.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="images/court4.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="images/court5.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="images/court6.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="menu_right">
    <div id="menu_right_top">
      <ul id="menulist">
        <li><a href src="#"><img src="images/buttons/articles_btn.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/buttons/articles_btn_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/buttons/articles_btn.png'" alt="Articles"/></a></li>
        <li><a href src="#"><img src="images/buttons/interviews_btn.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/buttons/interviews_btn_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/buttons/interviews_btn.png'" alt="Articles"/></a></li>
        <li><a href src="#"><img src="images/buttons/events_btn.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/buttons/events_btn_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/buttons/events_btn.png'" alt="Events" /></a></li>
        <li><a href src="#"><img src="images/buttons/team_btn.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/buttons/team_btn_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/buttons/team_btn.png'" alt="The Team" /></a></li>
        <li><a href src="#"><img src="images/buttons/contact_btn.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/buttons/contact_btn_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/buttons/contact_btn.png'" alt="Contact Us" /></a></li>
        <li><a href src="#"><img src="images/buttons/home_btn.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/buttons/home_btn_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/buttons/home_btn.png'" alt="Home" /></a></li>
      </ul>    
    </div>
    <div id="menu_right_bottom"><hr width="560px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="content_left">
    <p>
      <h2>News</h2>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
      text of the printing and
      typesetting industry. Lorem
      Ipsum has been the industry's s
      tandard dummy text ever since the
      1500s, when an unknown printer too
      k a galley of type and scrambled i
      t to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuri
      es, but also the leap into electro
      nic typesetting, remaining essenti
      ally unchanged. It was popularised
      in the 1960s with the release of L
      etraset sheets containing Lorem Ip
      sum passages, and more recently wi
      th desktop publishing software lik
      e Aldus PageMaker including versio
      ns of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="verticalLine">
     <font style="color: #2a3035;">.</font>
  </div>
  <div id="content_right_top"><h1>Have your say...</h1><hr>
    <?php
      $dbLink = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
          mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $dbLink);
          mb_language('uni');
          mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

      $getquery=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Comment_Table ORDER BY id DESC");
      while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))
      {
      $id=$rows['id'];
      $name=$rows['name'];
      $comment=$rows['comment'];
      echo $name . '<br/>' . '<br/>' . $comment . '<br/>' . '<br/>' . '<hr size="1"/>'
      ;}
      ?>
       </div>
       <div id="content_right">

         <form action="index.php" method="POST">
         <table>
        <tr><td>Name: <br><input type="text" name="name"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">Comment: </td></tr>
         <tr><td colspan="5"><textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea></td>  </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment"></td></tr>
        </table>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
     <div id="footer">
      <div id="footer_content">
      Copyright &copy Maltese Law
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  </center>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I can follow you; do you mean that if I submit a comment, and then refresh the page, the comment is added to the database a second time?

Comment: Isn't that normal? Most of the browsers are asking if you want to repost, because your previous action was POST reaching this page, and the refresh will repeat it.

Comment: You will need to use a different method, use a redirect or Ajax if possible, including sessions and a token. Worked fine for me, first post. Will only occur if user presses refresh, then it will repost what's in the browser's memory.

Comment: @Matthew Borg I think your code is fine. You just need to go about it in a different way and as I said earlier, *"You will need to use a different method, use a redirect or Ajax if possible, including sessions and a token."*

Comment: @DarylGill Yes a `header("Location:...");` would be a good method, yet I'm wondering if that won't cause an endless loop? The OP is better off to setup the comment box in either another page, or use it as an `include`.

Comment: @Fred If you issue the header in the `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` with the correct flushings.. After redirecting to the main home page, the globals will be unset, so PHP wont enter the conditions

Comment: @DaryGill Earlier you mentioned: 

unset($_POST); header("Location: index.php"); exit;

Could you kindly let me know where I am supposed to place this piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Redirection prevents a lot, in this case: Database memory wastage & some frustration**

The answer is that when you refresh the page, the browser resends the information to the server which then adds the information again thereby creating a duplicate.

So what you must do is you should have a mechanism to redirect the user to the page after submitting the data..

like so:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

just replace `http://www.example.com` with your page but make sure it is not `www.borgcarr.com/index.php` because it will result in an infinite redirect loop..

so what you have to do is redirect it to some other page, and unset the post variables...
on that other page you might have a button saying **« Back to home** or whatever...

so the whole process would be:

```
unset($_POST);
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

hope that helps, so just leave a comment telling if it worked...

however, the best bet here is to have a separate page to add comments and redirect them to the main page which displays the comments...

Answer (score -1):

As Said in my comment below.. I have a similar setup to this,

You could add the following:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $Errors = 0;
        if (empty($_POST['name'])){
            $Errors++;
        }
        if (empty($_POST['comment'])){
            $Errors++;
        }

        if ($Errors !== 0){
            echo "<script>alert('Please fill out all fields.');</script>";
        }else{
            $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO Comment_Table (name,comment) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment'])."') ");
                unset($_POST);
            if (!headers_sent()){
                header("Location: index.php");
            }else{
                echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=index.php">';
            }

        }

    }
```